# How to join ISet and child objects in nhibernate criteria api

Tags: nhibernate

If i have the following classes

```
public class Order
{

    public virtual ISet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

}


public class OrderItem
{

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

OrderItem has a one to one relationship with product. What would be the most effectient to get all of this from one sql request.

I'm using nhibernate criteria api. How would i add orderitems and product as jointypes

```
        using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Model.Order order = _session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
                .CreateAlias("OrderItems", "orderItems", JoinType.xxxx)

                .UniqueResult<Model.Order>();
                transaction.Commit();
                return order;
            }
            catch (HibernateException)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Close();
                _session.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.Order order = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id))
    .SetFetchMode("OrderItems", FetchMode.Eager)
    .UniqueResult<Model.Order>();
```